# we reach vs we are reaching

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

I am working on a flyer design, what is the right way to write:

> 1. "Join us before we are reaching the limit."
> 2. "Join us before we reach the limit."

And what is the difference between the two?
Is there a better (native) way to say this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is "Join us before we reach the limit."  The other sentence is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

*Before* and *after* are hardly ever followed by a continuous verb-form. I think this is because they are used to give a reference time, and it needs to be a point in time, not an extended period.